# Python finding n as 101 instead of 100

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Python loops are finding n as 101 instead of 100, I am getting the average of 5050 as 50 instead of 50.50, What could be the problem? How should I go through it? Here is my function.

```
def sum_and_average(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        total += i
    average = float(total/n)
    print "the sum is %d and the average is %f" %(total, average)

sum_and_average(100)
```

It returns:

```
the sum is 5050 and the average is 50.000000
```

Comment: @ayhan okay Let me try that.. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `float(total) / n`.

In Python 2 when one of the arguments is float, the calculation will be carried out in float.

But doing `float(total/n)` won't work, since `total/n` has already been calculated in integers, and `float`ing the result is already too late.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed help, I now understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

To get the average you want this:

```
average = float(total)/n
```

Some examples:

```
>>> float(101/2)
50.0
>>> 101/2
50
>>> float(101)/2
50.5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was wondering where the problem was.

Comment: FWIW, `1.0 * a / b ` is better than `float(a) / b`. It's faster, since it avoids a function call, and it's more general (it handles complex numbers properly). But really, it's better to use `from __future__ import division` unless you're using a really ancient version of Python that doesn't support that import.

Comment: @PM2Ring I've never written anything much in Python to know, but I'll remember that! Thanks for your input.

Comment: @PM2Ring Wow true that is really effective thinking.